# Passing A Function In Common Lisp

Tags: common-lisp

I've very new to lisp so please bear with me. The following code is an attempt at what I 'thought' was a way to pass a function, but it appears to be something else:

```
(defun hello-world () (format t "hello, world!"))                                     
(defun ll (x y) (+ (* 3 y)x))
(defun zz(x)(funcall(λ(x)x)x))
>(zz (hello-world))
>hello, world!NIL
>(zz (ll 3 4))
>15
>(zz 8)
>8
```

My question(s):
Is this an identity function? If not, why? Lastly, why is the last (x) required for the lambda expression? Any canonical source material would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me try to analyze your code step by step

```
(lambda (x) x)
```

This is a function which takes one argument, binds variable `x` to it, and returns `x`, i.e., the identity function.

```
(funcall (lambda (x) x) x)
```

This calls the aforementioned identity function on argument `x` (unrelated to the first two `x`'s in the expression), so this is the same as `x`.

```
(defun zz (x) (funcall (lambda (x) x) x))
```

This defines a new function `zz`, which, as discussed above, is the identity function.

Look at the values returned by your function calls, e.g.:

```
(zz (hello-world))
hello, world!NIL
```

`hello-world` *prints* "hello, world!" and *returns* `NIL`, which is passed to `zz`, which, in turn, return its argument intact as `NIL`.

Comment: YES! Thank you so much! I really needed a second pair of eyes(and my lambda calculus ain't so good yet...). At least now I feel I've made a little progress!